# Compile-time define in java

Tags: java

I am having a problem where I need to obtain some compile-time variable and change the code accordingly. Changing the way it works is not a option.

Here is how it works in c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("version: %d\n", version);
    printf("svn:     %d\n", svn);
    return 0;
}
```

```bsh
$ gcc -Dversion=1 -Dsvn=15 main.c -o main
```

```bsh
$ ./main
version: 1
svn:     15
```

How can i create that behavior in java?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: are you looking for something like macro in c?

Comment: You probably won't, but check [Maven's Resource Filtering plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). It is capable of pre-processing files before compilation, maybe replacing some values.

Comment: @acdcjunior That solution doesn't actually work since maven only filters *resource* files, not the source code files. So this would work on .txt and .xml files, but not on source code .java files.